# Twitter Bootstrap Buttons - Server Side code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use a twitter bootstrap button and add a Button Click event to it in ASP.NET / VB.NET in my code behind. Obviously the difference between the twitter button is that it is just a HTML input and the ASP:Button is different. So how do I target the twitter bootstrap button in my code behind?

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Add to Bookshelf</button></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `CssClass property`

Sample

```
        Button myButton= new Button();
        myButton.Text = "First";
        myButton.CssClass = "btn btn-large btn-primary";
        this.form1.Controls.Add(myButton);
```

now your button became a bootstrap button :p